# no such column en sql , ¿esta mal mi foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo el siguiente codigo en sql , y trato de imprimir  una suma con un where , pero parece que estoy haciendo mal usando las primary key y foreign key me pueden decir en que parte me equivoque? me tira el error Error: near line 31: no such column: ciudad

```
/* Create a table called NAMES */
CREATE TABLE auto(codaut integer primary key , marca varchar(20) , modelo varchar(20) , origen varchar(20) , precio integer);
create table cliente(rut integer primary key , nombre varchar(30) , comuna varchar(18) , ciudad varchar(15) , codaut integer , FOREIGN KEY (codaut) REFERENCES auto (codaut));


/* Create few records in this table */
insert into auto values(1 , "nissan" , "370Z" , "alemania" , 6000000 );
insert into auto values(2 , "audi" , "a1" , "alemania" , 14201181 );
insert into auto values(3 , "subaru" , "wrx" , "alemania" , 12874888 );
insert into auto values(4 , "porshe" , "cayman" , "italia" , 3967546 );
insert into auto values(5 , "buick" , "regal" , "italia" , 3712229 );


insert into cliente values(121192632 , "armando lillo" , "Calama" , "Calama" ,1 );
insert into cliente values(76893209 , "camila" , "arica" , "arica" ,2 );
insert into cliente values(134645253 , "matias" , "sierra gorda" , "sierra gorda" ,3 );
insert into cliente values(246145814 , "fernanda" , "taltal" , "taltal" ,4 );
insert into cliente values(133296905 , "leonardo" , "tocopilla" , "tocopilla" ,5 );


/* Display all the records from the table */
select * from auto;
select * from cliente;

/* aca imprime el promedio de los autos italianos mamma mia */

select avg(precio) from auto where origen="italia";

select sum(precio) from auto where ciudad="arica";
```

Comment: Pues el error te indica que la columna no existe, de hecho revisando tu código la columna `ciudad` existe en `cliente`

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en tu código lo que ocurre es que la tabla *auto* no tiene el campo *ciudad* (es la tabla de clientes la que tiene ese campo).

Debes corregir esta línea y obtener la información de otra manera:

```
select sum(precio) from auto where ciudad ="arica";
```